# Automated way to georeference borders in QGIS?

Tags: qgis, georeferencing

I have a picture of a map containing the borders of administrative areas, similar to this one:
[image]

I know how to georeference the picture using QGIS. Is there a way to let QGIS recognize the borders of the administrative units and convert them into polygons? Or do I have to do this manually?

I am aware of this post ([How to automatically extract borders from an old map?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/191524/how-to-automatically-extract-borders-from-an-old-map)), but its 6 years old.

Comment: Depending on the resolution and quality of the georefenced image you could use the raster calculator to extract the borders.

Comment: can you expand on why the old question is different to yours?

Comment: This look like a map made from GIS data so unless you're asking in a more general way it may be easier/quicker/more accurate to track the original administrative area polygon data than trying to recreate it...